# Does the integral converge $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(ibx)}{1+e^x}\,dx$ for $b>0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I try to calculate integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(ibx)}{1+e^x}\,dx.$$ Does it converge for $b>0$? Wolfram Mathematica shows contradictory results: for $b=2$ it converges, for $b=1$ and $b=3$ it does not. I need to calculate it.

Comment: No. $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^\infty$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Prove it, please.

Comment: "I don't want to think, I'll better ask." Boring. $\int_0^\infty$ clearly converges; $$\int_a^0\frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^x}\,dx=\int_a^0 e^{ibx}\,dx-\int_a^0\frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^{-x}}\,dx,$$ where the 3rd integral has a finite $a\to-\infty$ limit, and the 2nd one (hence the 1st one) doesn't.

Comment: To make things not so boring, the Fourier transform of $1/(1+e^x)$ exists in a [certain extended sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions).

Comment: I've met this integral in scientific paper T. Champel & V. P. Mineev (2001) de Haas–van Alphen effect in two- and quasi-two-dimensional metals and superconductors, Philosophical Magazine Part B, 81:1, 55-74. It was written without proof that it is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(ibx)}{1+e^x}dx=-\frac{i\pi}{\sinh(\pi b)}$. Now, I don't know what to do with it for my research.

Comment: Physicists are often not rigorous in math. Go figure what they mean.

Comment: @metamorphy I agree with you that the answer to the stated question “Does it converge?”) is something the OP could have put more effort into. But with the clarification about the result he/she is expecting, then it’s not appropriate to just shrug and blame physicists.  As you pointed out, there are Fourier transforms defined for $L^2$ functions or even (using other formalisms) for functions that are not even $L^2$, such as a constant, so your complaint is not really valid.

Comment: I would add that physicists often use other inputs (from concrete physical problems) to justify ther result. For example, other function limitation (or cutting) coming from specific physical conditions. Or, function may not have limit, but be highly oscillating, and any further treatment of these oscillating terms will effectively bring zero contribution.

Comment: A possible interpretation of the result is that $F(b) = \mathcal F[1/(e^x + 1)] = - \pi i \mathcal P(\operatorname {csch} \pi b) + \pi \delta(b)$ in the sense of distributions. If we consider only those test functions that vanish at $0$, then $(F, \phi)$ is equal to $-\pi i \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(b) \operatorname {csch} \pi b \, db$, we can ignore the principal value and the delta function.

Comment: Do you know where can I find the derivation of Fourrier transform of $1/(e^x+1)$ in extended sense? Or it is presence in a reference book? I tried to google it but failed.

Comment: @user2272592: posted an ["answer"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3999681) below; this may give some more words to google ;)

Comment: @Maxim I've posted a solution that uses a regularization approach.  I'd like to read your thoughts as always.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This note explains the comment (to the OP) by @Maxim regarding $\mathscr{F}\left[\frac{1}{e^x+1}\right](\xi)$ of a *tempered distribution*, provided that we define it as $\mathscr{F}\big[f(x)\big](\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i\xi x}\,dx$ for *regular* $f$.

Using the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), $$\frac{1}{e^x+1}=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}x}{e^{|x|}+1}+\frac{1-\operatorname{sgn}x}{2},$$ and the first term on the RHS has a *regular* Fourier transform $\color{LightGray}{\texttt{(todo: link)}}$: $$\mathscr{F}\left[\frac{\operatorname{sgn}x}{e^{|x|}+1}\right](\xi)=2i\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\xi x}{e^x+1}\,dx=\frac{i}{\xi}-\frac{\pi i}{\sinh\pi\xi}.$$ The FT of the remainder is found using $\mathscr{F}[1](\xi)=2\pi\delta(\xi)$ and $\mathscr{F}[\operatorname{sgn}x](\xi)=2i$[$\mathscr{P}\frac{1}{\xi}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory).

Comment: Nice succinct solution (+1).  I've just posted a solution that uses a regularization approach.  I'd enjoy reading your comments.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Probably something along these lines ...

Set $f(z) = e^{i\alpha z}/(1 + e^z)$ for complex $z$ and integrate round the closed contour running along the real axis from $z = -R$ to
$z = R$, then continuing on the semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane:

\begin{align}
I_1(R) &= \int_{-R}^R f(x)\, dx, \\
I_2(R) &= iR \int_0^\pi f(Re^{i\theta}) e^{i\theta}\, d\theta.
\end{align}

We're aiming for using Cauchy's integral theorem. On the semicircle
\begin{align}
f(Re^{i\theta}) &= \frac{\exp(i\alpha R e^{i\theta})}{1 + \exp(Re^{i\theta})} \\
&= \frac{\exp(-\alpha R \sin\theta + i\alpha R \cos\theta)}{1 + \exp(R\cos\theta + iR\sin\theta)}
\end{align}

- For $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, both $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are positive. The numerator is $O(e^{-\alpha R \sin \theta})$ and the denominator is $O(e^{R\cos\theta})$ so the ratio is $O(e^{-\alpha R \sin\theta - R\cos\theta})$.
- When $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$, $\sin\theta$ remains positive but $\cos\theta$ is negative. The numerator is $O(e^{-\alpha R\sin\theta})$ and the denominator is
  $O(1)$, so the ratio is $O(e^{-\alpha R\sin\theta})$.

All of this to justify that $I_2(R) \rightarrow 0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$. It follows from Cauchy's integral theorem, letting $R \rightarrow \infty$, that
$I_1(\infty)$ is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f$ in the upper half-plane. Here the poles of $f$ are simple and occur at $z_k = (2k + 1)\pi i$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots$. Verify that $\text{Res}(f, z_k) = -e^{-\pi\alpha (2k + 1)}$,
which yields:
\begin{align}
I_1(\infty) &= -2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\pi\alpha(2k + 1)} \\
&= -2\pi i e^{-\pi \alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2\pi \alpha k} \\
&= -2\pi i e^{-\pi \alpha}\frac{1}{1 - e^{-2\pi\alpha}} \\
&= -\frac{\pi i}{\sinh(\pi \alpha)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Does that mean that integral is infinite itself but its Cauchy principal value is finite?

Comment: Unfortunately, having the factor$ O(e^{-\alpha R \sin\theta - R\cos\theta})$ under the  integral is not enough to prove that the integral over big circle is equal to zero - Jordan's lemma requires that function in addition to this factor $\to0$ at ${\infty}$.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow you. We apply Jordan’s lemma to the integrand $f(z)\exp{iz}$. We evaluate the integral over big half-circle $I_R=\int_{R}f(R\exp(i\phi)) \exp(iR\cos(\phi)\exp(-R\sin(\phi))iR\exp(i\phi)d\phi$$<\int_{R}|f(R\exp(i\phi))|R\exp(-R\sin(\phi))d\phi $. Then we evaluate $\sin(\phi))>\frac{2}{\pi}\phi$ and, therefore, $\exp(-R\sin(\phi))<\exp(-R\frac{2}{\pi}\phi)$. After this evaluation we do the integration and get the bound - integrating from 0 to, let’s say, $\phi{1}$: $I_R<|f(R)|R\frac{\pi}{2R}(1-\exp(-R\frac{2}{\pi}\phi{1})$.

Comment: So, we don’t have problems at the area $\phi{1}>0$ (for instance, at $\phi{1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$), where our result is decreasing exponentially over $R$ - the real problem is in the area near $\phi=0$, where we need $|f(R|\to0$ prove that $I_R\to0$.

Comment: Thank you Svyatoslav, I appreciate your scrutiny. I'll have a closer look when I get a chance.

Comment: $f(z)$ can have a pole on the large semicircle, clearly the limit of $I_2(R)$ doesn't exist. Even if you choose semicircles avoiding the poles, say, by taking the limit of the sequence $I_2(2 n \pi)$, the limit may exist but not be equal to zero (it's simpler to consider large squares to show that).

Answer (score 2):

The integral $I^+(b)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^x}\,dx$ exists, both as an improper Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral.  In fact, by expanding $\frac{1}{1+e^x}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$ in a geometric series, we can write $I^+(b)$ in series form as

$$I^+(b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-ib}\tag1$$

But the integral $I^-(b)=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^x}\,dx$ fails to exist.  As has already been discussed by others on this page, we may interpret $I^-(b)$ as a distribution.

So, I thought it might be instructive to present an approach to evaluating the distribution $I^-(b)$ that is distinct to the other posted answers.  It is to that end that we now proceed.

---

Let $R>0$ and denote $I^-_R(b)=\int_{-R}^0 \frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^x}\,dx$ as the integral.  Note that $\lim_{R\to \infty}I^-_R(b)=I^-(b)$ in disribution.  Now, enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto -x$ and expanding $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ in a geometric series

$$\begin{align}
I^-_R(b)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(1-e^{-(n+ib)R})}{n+ib} \\\\
&=-\frac ib (1-e^{-ibR})-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(1-e^{-(n+ib)R})}{n+ib}\\\\
\end{align}$$

In the sense of distributions, $\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ibR}}b=\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+i\pi\delta(b)$.  (See the Proof in the Appendix herein)

Therefore, in the sense of distributions

$$I^-(b)=-i\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+\pi \delta(b)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n+ib}\tag2$$

---

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, the Fourier Transform of $f(x)=\frac1{1+e^x}$ is

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(b)=\pi\delta(b)-i\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+i2b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2+b^2}\tag3$$

The series in $(3)$ can be found using the Residue Theorem by integrating $\frac{\csc(\pi z)}{z^2+b^2}$ over a circular contour with radius $N+1/2$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and center at $z=0$ and then letting $N\to \infty$.  Proceeding reveals

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(n^2+b^2)}+\frac{1}{ib\sin(i\pi b)}=0$$

from which we find that

$$i2b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2+b^2}=\frac ib-i\pi \text{csch}(\pi b)\tag4$$

Substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$ yields the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\mathscr{F}\{f\}(b)=\pi\delta(b)-i\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+\frac ib-i\pi \text{csch}(\pi b)}$$

---

---

**APPENDIX:  Proof that $\displaystyle \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ibR}}{b}=\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+i\pi \delta(b)$**

**STEP $1$**

Let $\phi(b)$ be a Schwartz function.  We will show that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(b) \frac{\sin(bR)}{b}\,db=\pi \phi(0)$$

Integrating by parts with $u=\phi(b)$ and $v=\int_{-\infty}^b \frac{\sin(kR)}{k}\,dk$, and applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(b) \frac{\sin(bR)}{b}\,db&=-\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(b) \int_{-\infty}^b \frac{\sin(kR)}{k}\,dk\,db\\\\
&=-\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(b) \int_{-\infty}^{Rb} \frac{\sin(k)}{k}\,dk\,db\\\\
&=-\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(b)H(b)\,db\\\\
&=\pi \phi(0)
\end{align}$$

And we are done.

---

**STEP $2$**

Let $\phi(b)$ be a Schwartz function.  We will show that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(b)}{b}\,db$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$.  Then, applying the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{|b|<\varepsilon} \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db+\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{|b|>\varepsilon} \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db\\\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{|b|<\varepsilon} \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db+\int_{|b|>\varepsilon} \frac{\phi(b)}{b}\,db
\end{align}$$

Next, writing $\phi(b)=\phi(0)+\phi'(0)b+O(b^2)$ for $|b|<\varepsilon$ and noting that $\frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}$ is integrable and an odd function of $b$, we find that

$$\int_{|b|<\varepsilon} \phi(b) \frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db=O(\varepsilon)$$

Letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ we conclude

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(b)\frac{1-\cos(bR)}{b}\,db&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{|x|\ge \varepsilon}\frac{\phi(b)}{b}\,db\\\\
&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{\phi(b)}{b}\,db
\end{align}$$

---

**PUTTING STEPS $1$ AND $2$ TOGETHER**

Using the results in Steps $1$ and $2$ yields

$$\lim_{R\to \infty }\left(\frac{1-e^{-ibR}}{b}\right)=\text{PV}\left(\frac1b\right)+i\pi \delta(b)$$

Comment: $(1 - e^{i R b})/b$ in the appendix should be $(1 - e^{-i R b})/b$. If the goal is to derive everything from the first principles, we need to prove that the given series converge distributionally to regular distributions corresponding to their pointwise limits (one may use uniform convergence to show that). $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} (-1)^n/(n^2 + b^2)$ doesn't define a distribution ($1/b^2$ has many different regularizations).

Comment: @Maxim Thank you for the note.  I've edited the typographical error (i.e., the sign on the exponential).  I'm not sure as to the issue of the series.  The associated distribution is not $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+b^2}$.  Rather it is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n b}{n^2+b^2}$ which is absolutely and uniformly convergent for all $b$.  Note the sum starts at $n=1$ and so $\frac{b}{b^2}=\frac1b$ is not implicated from the series.

Comment: Is $I^+$ the pointwise limit (p.l.) or the distributional limit (d.l.)? If it's the p.l. obtained from the p.l. of $S = \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n - 1} e^{-n x} H(x)$, we need to show that we can interchange the integral and the sum in $\int_{\mathbb R} Se^{i b x} dx$. If it's the d.l., we need to show that $H(x)/(e^x + 1)$ is the d.l. of $S$. I'm just pointing out that in this case it's not completely trivial to show that the p.l.'s and the d.l.'s are equivalent. If all the other limits are d.l.'s and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ is a p.l., we need to show how we're obtaining a d.l. from a p.l.

Comment: @Maxim Note that $I^+(b)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{1+e^x}\,dx$ is well-defined as an improper Riemann integral or as a Lebesgue integral.   We represented $I^+(b)$ as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-ib}$, which converges conditionally for all $b\in \mathbb{R}$.  Next, we analyze $I^-_R(b)$ and find that it has one term that can be represented by the sum of a series that converges as $R\to\infty$ and a term that has only a distributional limit as $R\to \infty$.  We add $I^+(b)$ to $I^-_R(b)$, evaluate the sum of the series which has a closed form part plus ...

Comment: @Maxim ... plus the term $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{()^{n-1}e^{-(n+ib)R}}{n+ib}$ ... this term has a pointwise limit of $0$ AND a distributional limit of $0$ owing to the uniform convergence.  The result is an ordinary function $\frac ib -i\pi \text{csch}(\pi b)$, which is independent of $R$.  So, after evaluating the distributional limit of $\frac{1-e^{ibR}}{b}$, we reach the final result.  So, I don't believe their is any unresolved issue.

Comment: It's just a point that I think needs to be clarified. I'm talking only about the infinite series. We have $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N (-1)^{n - 1}/(n - i b)$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N (-1)^{n - 1} e^{-n x} H(x)$ (with $H(0) = 0$), is it the p.l. or the d.l., and how do we know that the p.l. and the d.l. are equivalent? In this case there is no issue, but that's because the series are uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

This will be not a purely mathematical but rather a physical illustration via the integrand regularization.

Lets consider $f(x,a)=\frac{\exp(ibx+ax)}{1+\exp(x)}$, where $a$ is a small parameter which we will finally set to zero. Let's consider the integral over the contour C - a rectangle from $-R$ to $R$ and from $0$ to $2\pi{i}$; counter clockwise.

[image]

The integrand is a single-valued function in the area, so $I(a,b)=\oint_C\frac{\exp(ibx+ax)}{1+\exp(x)}dx$. Taking integral along every line of the contour and due exponent periodicity $\exp(x+2\pi{i})=\exp(x)$ we get:

$I(a,b)=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\exp(ibx+ax)}{1+\exp(x)}(1-\exp(-2\pi{b}+2{\pi}ia))dx+I_1+I_2=2{\pi}iRes_{x=\pi{i}}\frac{\exp(ibx+ax)}{1+\exp(x)}=$$ =-2\pi{i}\exp(-\pi{b}+\pi{ia})$

$|I_1|<\int_0^{2\pi}|\frac{\exp(ibR+aR-bt+iat)}{1+\exp(R+it)}|dt<const\exp(-(1-a)R)\to0$ as $R\to{\infty}$ ($a<<1$)

$I_2=i\int_{2\pi}^0\frac{\exp(-ibR-aR-bt+iat)}{1+\exp(-R+it)}dt\to-i\exp(-aR-ibR)\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(-bt+iat)dt=$$=-i\exp(-aR-ibR)\frac{1-\exp(2\pi(ia-b))}{b-ia}$ as $R\to{\infty}$

$$\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\exp(ibx+ax)}{1+\exp(x)}dx\to-2\pi{i}\frac{1}{\exp(\pi{b}-\pi{ia})-exp(-\pi{b}+\pi{ia})}+i\frac{\exp(-aR-ibR)}{b-ia}$$

As soon as we set $a\to0$ we get $$\int_{-R}^{R}\to-\pi{i}\frac{1}{\sinh(\pi{b})}+i\frac{\exp(-ibR)}{b}$$

Second term is not strongly defined - the limit at $R\to{\infty}$ does not exist.
Physically speaking it is strongly oscillating but limited by value. Here we have the same situation, for instance, when we identify delta-function  $\delta(x)$ as $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(ikx)dk=\lim_{R\to{\infty}}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}\exp(ikx)dk=\lim_{R\to{\infty}}\frac{\sin(xR)}{\pi{x}}$

Limit does not exist, but any further manipulations (for instance, integrating with a smooth function) shows that this is actually delta-function which is equal to zero at any point except for zero.

All this is not of course a math proof - just an illustration.